# PowerShell Start-Process doing only partial installation

Tags: powershell, silent-installer

I am using the below PowerShell command to install a software. The command is installing all the dependencies requried (visual c++ etc.), but not installing the actual software. Any thoughts?

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'C:\temp\VCDM\vCDM Client\setup.exe' -ArgumentList '/S','/v','/qn' -NoNewWindow -passthru
```

Comment: Does the fabulous manual say that you have to use `/S /v /qn` for a silent installation?

Comment: Didn't get you.does that mean we shouldn't be using these options?

Comment: I don't know. Can you link the manual to that installer?

Comment: There is no manual .I am trying to automate the installation of some software

Comment: Not every software can be installed silently. And every software, that can be installed silently, may have different parameters to do it. So you cannot just use parameters that work on one software to do a silent install of another software. Is this the software you are talking about: https://support.vector.com/kb/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=d1586e2493352d907bd5b7527cba104c

Comment: That's correct.I am only looking to install the vCDM client.

Answer (score 2):

Not every software can be installed silently. And every software, that can be installed silently, may have different parameters to do it. So you cannot just use parameters that work on one software to do a silent install of another software. You have to check the documention of the software for its correct silent install options.

For the [vCDM Client](https://www.vector.com/us/en/products/products-a-z/software/vcdm/) software, the manual is available [here](https://support.vector.com/kb/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=d1586e2493352d907bd5b7527cba104c). Section 2.2.8.1 on page 69 is covering silent install. According to it, it does *not* install dependencies. So you have to do it by yourself. Further more, all available options and their usage are explained. `/v` expects a string that you do not provide. You should also check which parameters are mandatory and which are not.

If that is not enough to get it running, you should call their support, as it is not open source software, that everyone can debug.